# Can session_register store more than 1 value?

Tags: php

can session_register store more than 1 value? Because in my view-product page I might need to input the value in session_register into the database.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_school']))
{
    header("location: ../enter-icas/");
}
```

This is the login page.

```
$_SESSION['login_school'] = $myschoolcode;
header("location: ../view-products/");
```

This is the product page after the user login.

Currently the code above is storing schoolcode, how can I make the session store my school name also?

```
$myschoolcode = ($_POST['schoolcode']);
$mypassword = ($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT school_id FROM schools_info WHERE SchoolCode = '$myschoolcode' and Password 
= '$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active = $row['active'];
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myschoolcode and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1) {
session_register("myschoolcode");
$_SESSION['login_school'] = $myschoolcode;

header("location: ../view-products/");
}
```

Comment: use $_SESSION['school_name'] = "School Name";

Comment: Read the docs - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php - the answer is "yes"; but don't make your code dependent on a function that's going to be deprecated in the next version of PHP

Answer (score 2):

You can separately stores the value in two session variable,

```
$_SESSION['login_school_name'] = $login_school_value;
$_SESSION['login_school_code'] = $myschoolcode;
```

If you want to use same login_school in two session variable,you can have option of array,

```
  $_SESSION['login_school'] = array();
  $_SESSION['login_school']['name'] = $login_school_value;
  $_SESSION['login_school']['code'] = $myschoolcode;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your help.

Comment: Ooh, that's even worse than the solution I had in mind if multiple session variables were not an option. (use a single string value with a separator, like "school login|school name").

Comment: @MrLister : Please give your solution as answer....I would have oppurtunity to get more elegant solution of you....

Comment: OK, but only if @Rapide can make a case for being unable to use more than one session variable.

Comment: @MrLister But the problem is the school name is not requested when the user login, it is in the database. How do I get the the school code from the database and store inside the session? I've edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: @Rapide Then I'm not sure what the problem is. Why do you think you can't use `$_SESSION['login_school_name'] = $login_school_value;` like LolCoder says?